# Why was Christopher Eccleston the doctor for only one season?

Tags: doctor-who

When Dr. Who was started back up, they cast Christopher Eccleston as the doctor.  However, he was only kept for one season.  I quite like him as an actor and thought he did a good job.  Why was he the doctor for only one season?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Initially, he stated that he wanted to avoid being typecast so he quit to move on with his career. However, in [this statement in an acting class](http://badwilf.co.uk/?p=820), he tells a rather different story.

> I left Doctor Who because I could not get along with the senior
>   people. I left because of politics. I did not see eye-to-eye with
>   them. I didn’t agree with the way things were being run. I didn’t like
>   the culture that had grown up, around the series. So I left, I felt,
>   over a principle

He has always adamantly refused to come back for the 50th anniversary so the chances of more elaborate stories about the 9th doctor's adventures are very small. However, [there're some rumours](http://www.airlockalpha.com/node/9506/report-christopher-eccleston-returns-for-doctor-who-anniversary.html) he might come back for an all time special featuring all previous doctors so fingers crossed.

UPDATE: The anniversary special did not feature Ecclestone

Comment: Damn.  After recently getting into the new Who, he was my favorite one.  I wonder if there is anything to dig up that would signify if he'd return for an inter-connected special like they've done in the past (10th meeting the 5th is the most recent example) or if they do flashbacks to how the 8th became the 9th, which is still shrouded in mystery.

Comment: @TylerShads : Added some more on a rumoured return

Comment: Actually, Eccleston was on board with the anniversary, but they wouldn't hire Joe Ahearn to direct. Because Ahearn was born on the day An Unearthly Child first aired, he felt it would have been more symbolic. Moffatt wouldn't budge on his choice of director so Eccleston backed out. There was, however, a clip of Eccleston towards the end of Time of the Doctor.